# How to obtain the global position of Transfom Node nested inside a Proto

Tags: webots

Dear Webots community,

I'm currently trying to obtain the global position of a Transform (An attached part of a robot's body).
I now that the supervisor_API gives the possibility to get the position of a node.
However, as stated in in the documentation:

"If the requested node does not exist in the current world file or is an **internal node of a PROTO**, the function returns NULL"

Is there any way to access the nodes inside a Proto file using one of the supervisor options (by def, by id, etc.)?

Thank you very much in advance,

Best regards

Jan-Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed not possible by definition to access the internal nodes of a PROTO from a Supervisor.

To get the position of any part inside a PROTO, you could include a [GPS](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/gps) node where you want in the PROTO; the GPS API can retrieve the GPS node global position.

Answer (score 1):

With the latest versions of Webots, it is now possible to access internal nodes of a PROTO from a Supervisor. You should use the new [wb_supervisor_node_get_from_proto_def](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_node_get_from_proto_def) Supervisor API function. Once you obtained a pointer to the node, you can access its fields as you would do it for a normal node.